# Проблема с мульти апплоудом

Tags: ajax, php

Здравствуйте! Делаю скрипт мульти апплоуда фотографий на сервер, но проблема в том что апплоуд происходит только одной фотографии, подскажите в чем проблема. Ниже представлен код аплоудера!

Вот разметка:

```
<div class="filebutton" title="Image Upload">
<form id="imageform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action='ajax_image.php' multiple>
<span><input type="file" name="photoimg" id="photoimg"/></span>
</form>
```

Вот сам скрипт апплоуда:

```
    $path = "uploads/";
$valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif","JPG","JPEG","jpeg");
if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
 {
  $name = $_FILES['photoimg']['name'];
  $size = $_FILES['photoimg']['size'];
  if(strlen($name))
         {
    list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $name);
    if(in_array($ext,$valid_formats))
        {
        if($size<(2048*2048))
            {
            $actual_image_name = time().substr(str_replace(" ", "_", $txt), 5).".".$ext;

            $tmp = $_FILES['photoimg']['tmp_name'];
            if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path.$actual_image_name))
                {
                                $command=mysql_query("Insert into uploads(image_name) values('$actual_image_name')");
                $query=mysql_query("Select upload_id,image_name from uploads where image_name='$actual_image_name'");
                $result=mysql_fetch_array($query);
                $id=$result['upload_id'];

                echo "<img src='uploads/".$actual_image_name."' class='preview' id='$id'>";         
                    }
```

Подскажите в чем проблема ?Почему не работает апплоуд, заранее спасибо!

Comment: Не наблюдаю цикла для загрузки каждой из фото.

Comment: Спасибо! А что в этом коде стоит сделать сейчас что бы он смог загружать ? А то реально не могу понять... Классы тоже использовать не хотелось бы ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> А что в этом коде стоит сделать сейчас
> что бы он смог загружать

Ваш вариант переделывать не буду, но... Пример схематический, но рабочий. Проверки и т.д. сделаете сами.

```
if (isset($_FILES['photoimg'])){
    $dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/';
    $count = 0;
    foreach ($_FILES['photoimg']['name'] as $k => $v){
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photoimg']['tmp_name'][$k], $dir.$v)){
            $count++;
        }
    }
    echo 'Загружено '.$count.' фото.';
}
```

Кроме того, не забудьте всё правильно прописать в input:

```
<input type="file" name="photoimg[]" multiple>
```

Comment: Спасибо, а в какую часть данного когда нужно вставить проверки ?Просто на данный момент скрипт еще и зжимает фото, менять и переписывать код не хотелось бы вообще, только сделать его при годным для оплоуда не одной фотографии одновременно

Comment: Внутри цикла до загрузки. Т.е.:

    foreach ($_FILES['photoimg']['name'] as $k => $v){

        // тут проверяем текущий файл, сжимаем, прессуем, насилуем

        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photoimg']['tmp_name'][$k], $dir.$v)){